# SPSS - declare and use maximum number of cases as a constant

Tags: max, percentage, spss

I have data and I have to deliver to the client a script that contains the simple percentage of a certain variable grouped by another variable. The problem comes up when I try to calculate the percentage over the total number of cases (observations or rows, whatever you want to call it), but it seems that it's simply impossible.

I searched for code that would allow me to do something like declare a numerical constant variable that has the same value (maximum number of cases) for every case registered, something like this:

```
COMPUTE total_rows=$CASENUM. 
EXECUTE.

COMPUTE max_number_rows = MAX(total_rows) .
COMPUTE total_percentage = MyVariable / max_number_rows * 100 .
```

But it ain't working...

Over the internet I found that the only way to do it is with the `AGGREGATE` command, but I can't use it because I have to deliver **one and only one** script file and output file. I can't give the client one .sav with the original data and another one with the new table generated by the `AGGREGATE` function.

Answer (score 1):

[AGGREGATE](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_aggregate.htm) can be used directly to extract the total number of cases in the dataset:

```
AGGREGATE OUTFILE=* MODE=ADDVARIABLES /NRows=N.
```

Look up the notes for `AGGREGATE` and in particular the different aggregating functions that are available. In particular, which I am eluding to, is the distinction between the function `N` and `NU` where `N` returns a weighted total base size and `NU` an unweighted base size (of course if no weighting in affect then both yield the same value).